# How to use 'startwith' with 'if' statements in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop

I have the code:

```
name = ['Jan', 'Bob', 'Sarah', 'Billy']
if name.startswith('B'):
     name = 'B is for ' + name
```

I would like to change Bob's and Billy's name to say 'B is for Bob', and 'B is for Billy', but I get the error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'startwith'

I can't do it in a for loop because it converts the names to simple strings separated by a new line (I think). How can do the same without using a for loop?

Comment: `name` is not a _string_. It's a _list_. You need to iterate over this list and check each member of this list. Also, you have a typo, string method is `startswith`, no `startwith`.

Answer (score 3):

You have to modify each list element. For example:

```
names = ['Jan', 'Bob', 'Sarah', 'Billy']

for position, name in enumerate(names):
    if name.startswith('B'):
        names[position] = 'B is for ' + name

print(names)
```

Which will output:

```
['Jan', 'B is for Bob', 'Sarah', 'B is for Billy']
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much for this! I have never come across enumerate before

Comment: Well, remember to keep reading the docs, read tutorials and try examples. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension:

```
>>> name = ['Jan', 'Bob', 'Sarah', 'Billy']
>>> name = ["B is for " + n if n.startswith("B") else n for n in name]
>>> name
['Jan', 'B is for Bob', 'Sarah', 'B is for Billy']
```

This could be shortened to work with every name:

```
>>> name = ['Jan', 'Bob', 'Sarah', 'Billy']
>>> name = [n[0] + " is for " + n for n in name]
>>> name
['J is for Jan', 'B is for Bob', 'S is for Sarah', 'B is for Billy']
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the function is called "startswith", not sure if you only have the typo in your question or also your code.

The problem here is that you are trying to call a string function on a list element which is not possible. You have to iterate over the list, check at each index if it starts with a "B" and then update the names list at that index.